# How to spy on window.onclick within Jasmine unit testing

Tags: javascript, angular, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

How can I spy on a window.onclick **event** within Jasmine.
Tried to create a spy for window onclick and call this, but that didn't work.

The code which I want to cover with Jasmine:

```
setClass() {
    const input = this.document[0].querySelector('.wrapper');
    const inputButton = this.document[0].querySelector('.input-button');
    const inputField = this.document[0].querySelector('.input-field');

    this.window.onclick = function(event) {
        if (event.target !== inputButton && input.classList.contains('active')) {
            input.classList.remove('active');
        } if (event.target === inputField) {
            input.classList.add('active');
        } else {
            input.classList.remove('active');
        }
    };
}
```

This is what I tried:

```
describe('setClass method', () => {
    it('should add class active to the wrapper', () => {
        const classController = new classController(this.document, this.window);
        const elementWrapper = angular.element('<div class="wrapper"></div>');
        const elementBtn = angular.element('<button class="input-button"></button>');
        const elementInpt = angular.element('<input class="input-field" type="text">');

        spyOn(classController.document[0], 'querySelector').and.returnValues(elementWrapper[0], elementBtn[0], elementInpt[0]);
        spyOn(classController.window, 'onclick');

        classController.window.onclick(elementInpt);
        classController.setClass();

        expect(elementWrapper[0].outerHTML).toBe('<div class="wrapper active"></div>');
    });
});
```

The code is now covered untill this.window.onclick, how can I mock the event?

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems in your test.

1. You don't trigger the `click` event but install an other (invalid)
   click event handler on `window` by
   `classController.window.onclick(elementInpt)`
2. You invoke `classController.setClass()` after having (supposedly) triggered the
   `click` event. Therefore the event handler will not be ready on
   time.
3. You don't need a `spy` on `window.onclick` since `expect` checks the final changes made 
   on the HTML element.

Below you see the relevant changes to be made in your test.

```
it('should add class active to the wrapper', () => {
    ...

    // spyOn(classController.window, 'onclick'); // not needed

    classController.setClass();
    elementInpt.click();

    ...
});
```

Please also note that `window` and `document` are globally available and don't have to be provided in the `constructor` of your `ClassController` class.